# Should i dual boot windows 10 on ubuntu machine or vice versa

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Please explain pros and cons of dual booting windows 10 on ubuntu and ubuntu on windows 10

Comment: Do you want to dual-boot or to use virtual machines? When dual booting, you don't run one OS on another, you run either one **or** the other. Not both at the same time.

Comment: no i want to know better dual booting windows 10 from a existing ubuntu machine or ubuntu from a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 1):

In [Ubuntu's own wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu_after_Windows) it's recommended that you install Ubuntu **after** you have installed Windows 10.

> A Windows OS should be installed first, because its bootloader is very particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive, wiping out any data stored on it. If Windows isn't already installed, install it first. If you are able to partition the drive prior to installing Windows, leave space for Ubuntu during the initial partitioning process. Then you won't have to resize your NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu later, saving a bit of time.